# Spark: Issue while using event-time sliding window in streaming query

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am doing the real-time data streaming in Spark 2.2. As per my problem statement, I want to query the data within sliding window of 120 sec. duration. I am triggering the `streamingquery` after every 1 sec. Hence ideally, the query should run only one previous 120 sec. data(updated/fresh data).

But when I am running the query, it is running on entire data which has come before 120 sec. (old) data. This means that the window is sliding over the data which is already processed.

What may be the reason behind this? and how can I apply the window only on fresh data(unprocessed)?

Comment: please provide your code. It is hard to guess the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

With spark 2.2 and structured streaming you can specify a watermark on the event-time column you're performing your aggregations, the Scala code should look something like this, for a 120-second sliding-window that slides every second:

```
query
 .withWatermark("event-time-column", "120 second")
 .groupBy("event-time-column", "120 second", "1 second")
```

Thus, all the data and aggregation state from data older than 120 seconds is going to be dropped and only fresh data is processed

Full documentation here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html